# how to use ignore case in spring JPA @query?

Tags: sql, jpa, ignore-case

I have query as below:

```
@Query("SELECT b FROM Brand b WHERE b.name1 LIKE %:name1% or b.name2 like %:name2%")
List<Brand> findSome(@Param("name1") String name1, @Param("name2") String name2);
```

I want to ignore case so that I tried to modified it

```
@Query("SELECT b FROM Brand b WHERE lower(b.name1) LIKE lower(%:name1%) or lower(b.name2) like lower(%:name2%)")
```

But this looks like don't work, how can I do?

Comment: I got runtime error as "2016-02-06 16:58:30.368 ERROR 2136 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter        : line 1:74: unexpected token: %

antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected token: %"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is probably the syntax of your JP-Query. Try to use this:

```
lower(b.name1) LIKE concat('%', lower(:name1), '%')
```

Further reference: http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_like

Comment: Error is "org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Feature not supported: "VARCHAR +"; SQL statement:"